# Dual boot encrypted Ubuntu 13.04/12.04(option on installation CD) and Win7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7, encryption

Really sorry if someone had already asked this question, but I searched on this topic for a long time and only came up with the ones that used truecrypt. So, is it possible to do the following:

1. With win7 installation disk, install win7 on a 20gb partition I've made for it.
2. With Ubuntu LiveCD, somehow chose the option to install the encrypted version of the installation (which is on the menu).

The order may be reversed, but will be best if you install win7 first, to save the bootloader problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
For info, the following order is the easy way:

1. Install Windows
2. via Windows tools, reduce the Windows partition
3. install Ubuntu with the encryption option